# DialogFragment getArguments returns an empty value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I'm working on a fragment that calls a dialog fragment once a button is clicked. The Problem is once I want to get the arguments pass down in the dialog fragment it returns an empty argument. How can I fix this?

Fragment

```
mSaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
             SaveProductDialog saveProductDialog = SaveProductDialog.newInstance(mAddProductPresenter, String.valueOf(getmProductName().getText());
             saveProductDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "SaveProduct");
}
```

DialogFrament

```
public static SaveProductDialog newInstance(Presenter presenter, String productName){
        SaveProductDialog saveProductDialog = new SaveProductDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARGS_PRESENTER, presenter);
        args.putString(ARGS_PRODUCT_NAME, productName);
        saveProductDialog.setArguments(args);
        return saveProductDialog;
}

 @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //This returns an empty string instead of the presenter object
        AddProductPresenter addProductPresenter = (AddProductPresenter) getArguments().getSerializable(ARGS_PRESENTER);

}
```

Let me know if you need more details regarding my code. Thank you!

Comment: does ARGS_PRODUCT_NAME return data

Comment: @PhanVanLinh it also returns an empty string..

Comment: are you sure the data passed into newInstance is not null? In my test code, the value returned normally

Comment: yes. when it is creating a new instance the arguments pass are not null. but when accessed in the onCreateView it returns null or an empty string

Comment: I have the same problem